# Implementing Listener from Java in C#

Tags: java, c#, interface, listener

I'm trying to write a C# program. The functionality is already implemented (But in Java).

Is there any way to implement the "DeviceController.OnDeviceControllerListener"-Interface right in the method like in Java?
I need to implement and customize the override-methods(onError, onRead and onInsert) like in the Java code example:

```
deviceController.setOnDeviceControllerListener(new DeviceController.OnDeviceControllerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(ControllerError.Error error, String message) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRead(MobileServiceList<Device> devices) {
            if(devices == null || devices.size() == 0) {
                deviceController.insert(context, device);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInsert(Device device) {
        }
    });
```

I hope you understand my problem. It's hard to explain for me.

Comment: you can rewrite the funcionality from java code to C# ?

Comment: I already wrote the whole other functionality. There are sone asynchronous methods in my program and on the end of them I want to return to this methods(onError,...)

Comment: Use a tool such as sharpen can save you tons of time.

Comment: Sharpen doesn't really do much in my case because I'm porting an app from Android to WindowsPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create your own interface like

```
interface IOnDeviceControllerListener
{
        void OnError(ControllerError.Error error, String message);
        void OnRead(MobileServiceList<Device> devices);
        void OnInsert(Device device);
}
```

next class:

```
DeviceControllerListener : IOnDeviceControllerListener
{
   //  implementation
}
```

In your controller define method (in your case setOnDeviceControllerListener) which parameter is IOnDeviceControllerListener, set implementation in this case DeviceControllerListener and in implementation of devicecontroller class call methods of IOnDeviceControllerListener

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I assume it is not possible to do this like I did in Java, so I have to make separate classes.

Comment: @TableCreek - correct, C# doesn't support anonymous inner classes like your example.  The idiomatic C# way for listener-like interfaces is to use events and delegates instead.

Comment: Inner classes it's called... Thank you :)
Okay, I will ask google for more informations about events and delegates.

Comment: @Paolo: The problem with the idiomatic C# way is that it only works well for the simplest examples - i.e., single method, no fields.  Creating a new class to implement the interface or extend the abstract class handles all cases.